# Suggest apps for opening .mdl & .spr files

Tags: files

One app that can open .mdl files and another app that can open .spr file.

Comment: What are `.mdl` and `.spr` files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.mdl is part of Matlab. There is no software in the repositories for Matlab except for a package offering support files for a better working Matlab on Debian systems. The [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB) does offer instructions on how to install Matlab. There is no free software to open .mdl and you need to [purchase a copy of Matlab](http://nl.mathworks.com/downloads/). If this is something you need just for this 1 time you might be able to get away with a trial version.

.spr You mean a Foxpro file? That DOS software was created in 1993 and ended somewhere in 2007. Maybe you can get it to work in [WINE](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=296) but installing an old Windows (98? Me?) in a Virtualbox would be an easier option.

Answer (score 2):

.mdl file is a simulink model file. It can be open with MATLAB. You will have to buy it or use the free trial version [site](http://mathworks.com).

The SPR file extension is associated with Visual FoxPro database executable wrapper file. is a Microsoft relational database program.So there is no direct app in ubuntu to run this.But you could install Visual FoxPro. [Reffer here](http://www.paulmcnett.com/vfp/wine/vfp-wine-whitepaper.pdf)